# How do I integrate Plotly realtime updating graphs with React JS without rerender of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, plotly

I would like to use both React JS and plotly in my web app. I want plotly to graph realtime data, but I want to avoid a complete rerender of the graph everytime a new point is added. Plotly graphs have an update function that makes it so the entire graph isn't destroyed/rerendered.

So I have a few questions.
1. Is it possible to use react components to represent a plotly graph and have it update realtime without a full rerender of the graph?
2. If the above is not possible, is there a work around?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70068221/react-plotly-js-re-draws-graph-component-when-data-point-is-changed/73889261#73889261

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent your component from re-rendering when the data you use to update the plot changes. I'm currently doing exactly this with a canvas based project so it should work with plotly as well.

Edit: My shouldComponentUpdate looks like this, basically I only need to re-render the canvas if the size it's given changes not when the data changes.

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.height !== nextProps.height ||
       this.props.width !== nextProps.width) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: I'll report back shortly to see if this works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question:

1 - Yes you can, Plot.ly provide a NPM lib for that, react-plotly.js, you can see more details in the [docs](https://plot.ly/javascript/react/)

To work with real time update, you need to prepare your React Component to handle that, managing the React Lifecycle properly and work with Plot.ly graph update, more explained in this [post](https://medium.com/@jmmccota/plotly-react-and-dynamic-data-d40c7292dbfb).